# Click() method not working using C# Selenium IDE

Tags: c#, selenium, onclick, click

I am trying to execute a selenium test from c#. I have recorded the test on the selenium IDE and have verified it works using the IDE tool. The test is a simple proof of concept. Browse to the united airlines web site, enter some flight info on their search widget and invoke a search. When I run the project everything works except that the click on the search button does not invoke the click as it does when using the Selenium IDE.

Non working line with no errors thrown

```
 driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentInfo_Booking1_btnSearchFlight")).Click();
```

Full Code

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
baseURL = "http://www.united.com/";
verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
enter code here
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/web/en-US/default.aspx?root=1");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentInfo_Booking1_Origin_txtOrigin")).Clear();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentInfo_Booking1_Origin_txtOrigin")).SendKeys("fort lauderdale, fl");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentInfo_Booking1_Destination_txtDestination")).Clear();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentInfo_Booking1_Destination_txtDestination")).SendKeys("New York/Newark, NJ (EWR - Liberty)");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentInfo_Booking1_DepDateTime_Depdate_txtDptDate")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentInfo_Booking1_DepDateTime_Depdate_txtDptDate")).Clear();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentInfo_Booking1_DepDateTime_Depdate_txtDptDate")).SendKeys("4/7/2014");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentInfo_Booking1_RetDateTime_Retdate_txtRetDate")).Clear();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentInfo_Booking1_RetDateTime_Retdate_txtRetDate")).SendKeys("4/14/2014");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentInfo_Booking1_btnSearchFlight")).Click();


String test = driver.PageSource;
```

Comment: @bit thanks for the suggestion, I did try this but achieved the same results.

Comment: Try adding a Wait() or Sleep() before you perform those operations. sometimes, a previous Click() does some processing and disables the UI, hence wait for sometime and then try doing the next operation..

Comment: @bit I tried a thread sleep for five seconds. I also removed any other click events prior to the click in question. Great suggestions by the way not sure why this is not working.

Comment: Another way out could be Invoking the JS method wiried to the button Click()..

Comment: One more way out is trying to Click() the the parent element.. the code would look like 

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentInfo_Booking1_btnSearchFlight']/ancestor::div[1]")).Click();

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there are two `ctl00_ContentInfo_Booking1_btnSearchFlight` on the page.  The first is a `div`, the second is the button you want to click.

Try this instead:

```
FindElement(By.CssSelector("input#ctl00_ContentInfo_Booking1_btnSearchFlight")).Click();
```